# Is there an npm-package for google maps with an option for changing the color of each individual marker on the map dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I would like to change the color of each individual marker on the map dynamically.

The colors are indicating different categories (restaurant, gas station, etc.) and the user should be able to customise and add categories. I would like to achieve this by changing the map marker colors dynamically.

Is there an npm for that? 
I already tried vue-googlemaps but there is no option to change the color of the markers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with https://github.com/eregnier/vue2-gmap-custom-marker
It is the plugin for vue-google-maps.

Comment: Do you know if it's compatible with vue2-google-maps?

Comment: Ofcourse, it's a plugin for https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps  
and https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps refers to it

Comment: I tried implementing google maps in the app with vue2-google-maps but the map is not showing. I inspected it and the vue-map element is there, I just can't see it. It is just a blank container. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Lets separate it to another question - post the new one and put all the corresponding code inside

Comment: I created the question. You can find it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690156/how-to-display-google-maps-with-vue2-google-maps