# How to display Google Maps with vue2-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I would like to use vue2-google-maps in my app but the map is not showing. I followed the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) carefully on how to use it but the only thing I see is a blank white page instead of google maps. There are no errors in the console.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <gmap-map :center="{
      lat: 47.2736,
      lng: 16.0843
    }"></gmap-map>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {}
  }
</script>
```

As you can see it's the simplest possible implementation but all I see is a blank white page. I inspected the page and I can see the vue-map container and all the elements but the map doesn't show in the app.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I just had to add the `zoom` prop:

```
<template>
  <gmap-map :center="{
      lat: 47.2736,
      lng: 16.0843
    }" 
    :zoom="7"></gmap-map>
</template>
```